# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when popViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am pushing BViewController from A properly. B contains a webview that starts loading a page when viewDidLoad. I am getting a strange behavior when popping B to A,

1. If webview finishes its load and then I execute popViewController (IBAction when touchUpInside on a toolbar button), popped to A so everything works perfectly.
2. However, if I popViewController immediately before webview ends its load, app crashes due to exc_bad_access. why? view is already loaded!

I checked on both situations viewcontrollers that are on navigation stack. Both cases with same result, 2 same objects, no difference!

```
-(IBAction)goBackOrg:(id)sender{

    NSArray *viewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;

    [[self navigationController]  popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

}
```

and for previously pushing it, I am using

```
if(!self.BController){

            self.BController = [[BViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BViewController" bundle:nil anUrlDest:urlSocial];
        }

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:self.BController animated:NO];
```

Comment: Are you setting delegate for UIWebView?

Comment: yes, uiwebview delegate is set, but does it affect to navigation??

Comment: Yes, in dealloc method, try setting webView.delegate = nil;

Comment: @Paramasivan sure, thats it! thanks! +1 for helpful comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs when you're trying to access an object that has been deallocated.

So the following could be your problem: when you pop ViewController B, it is being unloaded. If the web view loading finishes after ViewController B is unloaded, some piece of callback code is getting executed that is trying to do something with your ViewController or its view (or similar).

Comment: mmm sounds logical! So when popping, B is unloaded and after that webview tries to notify an event to viewcontroller that not exist anymore, right? so set its delegate to nil before popping should do the trick! I appreciate so much your help!

Comment: Yup it's exactly that sort of problem. 
Note that if you're using ARC, the zeroing of weak references may deal with nilling off a delegate for you. More info here: http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-07-16-zeroing-weak-references-in-objective-c.html

Answer (score 0):

May be You are loading your webView on `Thread` and when you are using thread then you cannot do changes in UI otherwise your app will crash.

So just do this task on mainThread .